# Identify a Group of Entries in Database

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch to read entries from a database and process them accordingly. So far I write the entries, store all their primary keys in a list and set this list as one of the Job's parameters. This works fine for small batches but if there are 100s of entries the list gets to big to be stored as a parameter. So I was planning to store some sort or unique field that is common for all the entries pertaining to the same job and only pass this key as a parameter, I previously considered using the job execution id but this is generated after the job is launched so by the time the reader initialiases it might be too late. So I though of the following options:

1. Generate a hash using fields such as date/time, username of the person that submitted the job etc. **Question**: Are there any good algorithms to do this?
2. Generate an incrementable ID. **Question**: What is the best way to do this? **Question**: Can PostgreSQl sequences be used in such cases? (note: multiple entries will have the same key so I don't think it can be done using the `@GeneratedValue` annotation, please correct me if I'm wrong)
3. Do you have better ideas?

I think it would also be beneficial if you explain why you might prefer one solution over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a sequence in my database, adding the following bean in my configuration:

```
<bean id="batchSequence" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.PostgreSQLSequenceMaxValueIncrementer">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="incrementerName" value="batch_id" />
</bean>
```

Autowiring the above bean where necessary and then using the `nextLongValue()` method to generate a increment the sequence and get the new number.